# Removing package group except some packages

Tags: archlinux, pacman-package-manager

So, I was trying to remove GNOME by

```
sudo pacman -Rsn gnome
```

but I got the error

> checking dependencies...
>   :: removing networkmanager breaks dependency 'networkmanager' required by network-manager-applet

In fact, I don't want to remove the package `networkmanager`, that is contained in the package group `gnome`. How can I remove the whole group `gnome` except `networkmanager`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=117144), even if I don't know if it's the best solution.

Basically you have to generate the list of the packages from the group package (e.g., `gnome`) by typing

```sh
sudo pacman -Qgq gnome > pkglist
```

After that you have to remove from the generated file `pkglist` all the package names that you don't want to remove. And now you have simply to remove the packages by giving in input to pacman the `pkglist` file, that is

```sh
sudo pacman -R - < pkglist
```

Comment: More condensed would be `pacman -Qgq gnome | grep -v networkmanager | sudo pacman -R -`, but your version is more clear.